# ReactJS onClick arguments not getting passed to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component with an injected Mobx store that has the following method:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    propertyChangeNotifications: true,
    smsNotifications: false
  }
}

updateNotifications = (type, value) => {
  this.props.uiStore.updateProfile(type, value)
}
```

I am passing this method as a prop to a child component:

```html
<ProfileDetails {...this.props.uiStore.profile} updateNotifications={()=> this.updateNotifications()} />
```

The child component has another method:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  // Get profile data from props
  const {
    propertyChangeNotifications,
    smsNotifications,
    person: {
      fiscalId,
      residentialAddress,
      name,
      lastName,
      phoneNumber,
      type,
      email
    }
  } = props

  // Set state according to props
  this.state = {
    name: name,
    lastName: lastName,
    fiscalId: fiscalId,
    residentialAddress: residentialAddress,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    type: type,
    email: email,
    propertyChangeNotifications: propertyChangeNotifications,
    smsNotifications: smsNotifications
  }
}

handleCheckbox = (type) => {
  this.props.updateNotifications(type, !this.state[type])
  this.setState({
    [type]: !this.state[type]
  })
}
```

That I am passing to a semantic UI checkbox component:

```html
<Checkbox toggle label="Notify via SMS " checked={smsNotifications} onChange={()=> this.handleCheckbox('smsNotifications')} />
```

Now what happens is that the Checkbox method (`this.handleCheckbox`) gets called with the correct argument. Then the `this.props.updateNotifications` method gets called with the correct arguments as well, but the function in the parent component (`updateNotifications`), gets called with `undefined`, `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass the function itself, not "invoke the function". Delete () here.

```
<ProfileDetails
    {...this.props.uiStore.profile}
    updateNotifications={this.updateNotifications}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is, at all the places you are `binding` the method twice, one by using

```
this.updateNotifications={() => this.updateNotifications()} //here you are calling the function with no parameter.
```

And one by:

```
updateNotifications = () =>
```

Just remove the first way from all the places, it will work.

Simply use:

```
this.updateNotifications={this.updateNotifications}
```

and define the function by using `arrow function`:

```
updateNotifications = () =>
```